"ORA-00904: "SECONDS": invalid identifier" is thrown by Oracle while running simple insert statement, but the column seconds exists in the table
I am getting an ORA-00904 error from my Oracle database, while trying to run the following query from my Java application:
String sql =
      "insert into LOADER_COUNT_STATUS (facility, count, author, run, created, ended, seconds) \n" +
      "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement ps = null;

ps = db.getPreparedStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, facility);
ps.setInt(2, count);
ps.setString(3, author);
ps.setLong(4, run);
ps.setDate(5, new java.sql.Date(startClock.getTime()));
ps.setDate(6, new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()));
ps.setLong(7, ((Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() - startClock.getTime()) / 1000));
int rowCountUpdated = ps.executeUpdate();

getPreparedStatement() is just a thin wrapper over java.sql.connection.prepareStatement(), and every other method is directly from java.sql
Here's the DDL for LOADER_COUNT_STATUS:
CREATE TABLE SPEC.LOADER_COUNT_STATUS
(
  ID           NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 8461 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1 NOCYCLE CACHE 20 NOORDER NOKEEP) NOT NULL,
  FACILITY  VARCHAR2(64 BYTE),
  COUNT    NUMBER,
  CREATED      DATE                             DEFAULT sysdate,
  AUTHOR   VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
  "COMMENT"    VARCHAR2(64 BYTE),
  RUN       NUMBER(38),
  ENDED        DATE                             DEFAULT sysdate,
  SECONDS      NUMBER(38)
)

How do I get rid of this particular error? I don't think this is an issue of case-sensitivity, as these errors only pop up when the column name in the DDL is enclosed in double-quotes.

Your table is SPEC.LOADER_COUNT_STATUS (i.e. the LOADER_COUNT_STATUS table owned by the SPEC schema.
You do not show how you are connecting your Java program to the Oracle database but:
insert into LOADER_COUNT_STATUS (facility, count, author, run, created, ended, seconds)
values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Will try to insert into a LOADER_COUNT_STATUS table in the schema owned by the user you connected to. If you are not connecting to the SPEC user then it will try to use a table with the same name in your local schema (or via an alias); that is probably not going to be the same table and may not have the same columns.
Instead, use:
insert into SPEC.LOADER_COUNT_STATUS (facility, count, author, run, created, ended, seconds)
values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)


As an aside, you should probably use a GENERATED column for the SECONDS:
ALTER TABLE SPEC.LOADER_COUNT_STATUS
  DROP COLUMN seconds;

ALTER TABLE SPEC.LOADER_COUNT_STATUS
  ADD seconds NUMBER(38) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((ended - created) * 86400);

Then the SECONDS column will always match the bounds defined by CREATED and ENDED; you do not risk getting into the situation where someone modifies either ENDED or SECONDS without also updating the other value and they become out-of-sync.
Once you do that then you will not need to set the SECONDS column.

Thanks a lot! I went through my db connection string, and I am indeed connected as the user SPEC. Your answer seemed like a very plausible explanation but I don't think that this is the solution.
On a side note, thanks for the tip about using a generated column.

Seconds are keyword in Oracle, you need to escape it using duoble qutaotion "
However, the double quotation is special charactare in Java, so you need to escape it too using \".
So, you should do something like this:
String sql = "insert into LOADER_COUNT_STATUS (facility, count, author, run, created, ended, \"seconds\") \n" +
          "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

Good Luck

SECONDS is not a reserved word in Oracle and you can use it without quotes. fiddle

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html

My bad, I confused it with the "SECOND" function.
https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsecondfunc.html

@JalalKiswani That documentation you link to is for JavaDB and not for the Oracle Database. Oracle does not have a SECOND function.

@MT0,  I think I need to start taking some pills to regain my focus :) , sorry guys
